# {regex} Match Users's input IP address even when the input is empty

Tags: regex

## 1. Want i want to achieve

Match Users's input IP address even when the inputted is empty

## 2. What i have done

```
^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$
```

Matches correctly when the inputted IP exists (like 5.5.5.5)
  but it does not match the empty case. 
Test with https://regex101.com/

[matchingInputIpNotEmpty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94UkQ.jpg)

## 3. More details

```
(^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$)?
```

This matches the empty input but also any letter or numeric which i dont want.

[matchingInputIpEmpty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4V9e.jpg)

## /* Programming language */

Expect / Tcl -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect

## Question

How to match Users's input IP address even when the input is empty?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After starting with `^`, try having an optional group made up of digits/periods, followed by the end of the group and `$`. You may also repeat `\d+\.` in a group to keep the regex more DRY:

```
^(?:(?:\d+\.){3}\d+)?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/oQ3UIN/2

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance. It works in regex101 but not in my except script " if {([regexp {^(?:(?:\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$)?)$} $srcIpAddr] " . The script matches literal like " 5.5.5jhjhg.5 "

Comment: If you can't figure out how to implement it properly, you should edit your question to clarify the programming language you're using and a [MCVE]